# Does the following inequality hold? $|x_1a_1+x_2a_2|<a_1(|x_1+x_2|)$

Tags: inequality

Consider that $x_i$ is a complex number and $0<a_1<a_2$. Does the following inequality hold?

$|x_1a_1+x_2a_2|<a_1(|x_1+x_2|)$

Comment: If $x_{1} = 0$, the inequality is obviously false.

Answer (score 3):

This inequality does not hold for whenever both $x_1$and $x_2$ are non-positive.

Answer (score 1):

In the spirit of [teaching you to fish](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/give_a_man_a_fish_and_you_feed_him_for_a_day;_teach_a_man_to_fish_and_you_feed_him_for_a_lifetime), note that if $a_{1} \neq 0$, then
$$
x_{1}a_{1} + x_{2} a_{2} = a_{1} \bigl[x_{1} +  x_{2} (a_{2}/a_{1})\bigr],
$$
so if $0 < a_{1}$, then $|x_{1}a_{1} + x_{2} a_{2}| < a_{1}\, |x_{1} + x_{2}|$ if and only if
$$
|x_{1} +  x_{2} (a_{2}/a_{1})| < |x_{1} + x_{2}|.
\tag{1}
$$
As noted in the comments, if $x_{1} = 0$, this is false for all $a_{2} > a_{1}$ and all complex $x_{2}$.

If instead $x_{1} \neq 0$, write $z = x_{2}/x_{1}$ and $a = a_{2}/a_{1} > 1$, and divide out $|x_{1}| > 0$ to deduce (1) holds if and only if
$$
|1 + az| < |1 + z|.
\tag{2}
$$
Geometrically: "If $z$ gets farther from $0$ (i.e., if $z$ is replaced by $az$ with $a > 1$), does $1 + z$ get closer to $0$?"

The answer is clearly "no". This formulation should make clear that minor modifications, e.g., "If $0 < a_{1} < a_{2}$ and $x_{1}$, $x_{2}$ are complex, is $|x_{1}a_{1} + x_{2} a_{2}| < a_{2}\, |x_{1} + x_{2}|$?", are also false.